# List of Word.Version values

Tags: vba, ms-word, version

Microsoft have added a new function called `saveas2`to Word automation from Version 2010.

I need to write code that checks if this method exists (rather than just calling it and failing).

I can retrieve the version by calling `Word.Application.Version`but I can't find a list that maps the value I get from this function (14.0) to word versions.  Unfortunately I don't have every version of word installed to make my own list.

I have searched but, have been unable to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following list do the job:

```
Office 97   -  7.0
Office 98   -  8.0
Office 2000 -  9.0
Office XP   - 10.0
Office 2003 - 11.0
Office 2007 - 12.0
Office 2010 - 14.0
Office 2013 - 15.0
```

You just have to declare them as `constants` and you're good to go. Pity that VBA does not allow `structures` like in .NET.